# Move file from one location to another location in window c++

Tags: c++

Simple code for moving file to another location using window 10 visual studio c++ 2015.  In window how to move file from one location to another.

I have a text file at location D:\data.txt . I want to change its loaction to C:\total data\data.txt .

```
#include <cstdio>
int main (void)
{
std::rename ("old_name", "new_name");
return 0;
}
```

I already use rename fuction for moving using  but it not works further details  https://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/132322-file-move-programmatically

Just i want to change location of file.

Comment: Not works  #include <cstdio>
int main (void)
{
std::rename ("old_name", "new_name");
return 0;
}

Comment: Please [edit] your post with additional information. Ideally provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Please be more specific than "it not works".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes the name of the file or directory specified by oldname to newname.
If oldname and newname specify different paths and this is supported by the system, the file is moved to the new location.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  int result;
  char oldname[] ="D:\\data.txt";
  char newname[] ="C:\\datadull\\newname.txt";
  result= rename( oldname , newname );
  if ( result == 0 )
    puts ( "File successfully renamed" );
  else
    perror( "Error renaming file" );
  return 0;
}
```